# Why would fetch escape html special characters differently for different servers?

Tags: wordpress, next.js, fetch, wordpress-rest-api

I have a really odd one.

We have 2 WordPress sites, production and QA. These are essentially mirrors of one another.

I'm pulling menu data using the WordPress REST API from a menu that is identical in each environment.

The menu item in question in the WordPress admin shows up as "Something & Something". Here is where it gets weird.

- Postman renders the text identical for both envs: "Something &amp; Something"
- Curl renders the text identical for both envs: "Something &amp; Something"
- **NextJS fetch** renders "Something &#038; Something" for production and "Something &amp; Something" on QA.

Does anyone know why this would be different? It's super baffling.